# Replacing NaN value with None fill the value from the previous row in a DataFrame (pandas 1.0.3)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Not sure if it is a bug, but I am unable to replace NaN value with None value using latest Pandas library. When I use `DataFrame.replace()` method to replace NaN with None, dataframe is taking value from previous row instead of None value. For example,

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [10, 20, np.nan], 'y': [30, 40, 50]})
print(df)
```

Outputs

```py
      x   y
0  10.0  30
1  20.0  40
2   NaN  50
```

And if I apply replace method

```py
print(df.replace(np.NaN, None))
```

Outputs. Cell(X, 2) should be None instead of 20.0.

```py
      x   y
0  10.0  30
1  20.0  40
2  20.0  50
```

Anyone help is appreciated.

Comment: Just curious, why do you want to replace `np.NaN` by `None`?

Comment: This looks like a bug indeed, using a dictionary does give the correct output: `df.replace({np.NaN : None})`. But then I again, I have the same question as Quan Hoang.

Comment: I am inserting records to SQL Server using pyodbc, and None value is treated as NULL, but NaN value is treated as string.

Comment: Thanks Erfan, your suggeted solution solved the issue. Appreciate your help.

Comment: Makes sense, but are you using the `to_sql` pandas method for inserting your data to the database? See [link](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html)

Comment: Using cursor.execute followed by a insert statement. Would you say to_sql  be a better approach?

Comment: Yes I would use, to_sql. Since you use `cursos.execute` you have the connection to the database setup, to inserting it with `to_sql` makes it way easier.

Comment: Will definitely looking it and considering that option. Again, thank you for your help sir, and have a nice day. Stay safe.